# Make ASP.NET core 3.1 app use SSL certificate without installing .NET Core SDK

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl, ssl-certificate

I used a following PowerShell command sequence to generate, install and use an self-signed SSL certificate:

```
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName @("localhost") -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"

$certKeyPath = "c:\certs\contoso.com.pfx"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'password' -AsPlainText -Force
$cert | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certKeyPath -Password $password
$rootCert = $(Import-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certKeyPath -CertStoreLocation 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Root' -Password $password)

netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:44357 appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} certhash=55c6f3cc7464060043cd1b738b93c3ad82caaa43
```

Ever command has finished successfully.

But when I start ASP.NET Core 3.1 application it still considers it hasn't any certificate.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
> Unable to start Kestrel.
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
> To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.

Unfortunately `dotnet dev-certs https` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` require that .NET Core SDK is installed, but it shouldn't be there! This is a production server!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use Kestrel directly instead of a reverse proxy like Nginx?

Comment: MaartenDev, there is no special reason for that. It just already runs on a development machine and I want to simplify my life while copying the whole to the production environment. Otherwise comes another guy who knows another server and then I have to learn that too :)

Comment: I don't want to delete my comment. This is a really broad question and my question tries to narrow down your reasoning behind this question. Tagging users is not needed, users are automatically notified if they place a comment on a question.

Comment: How are you starting the application in the production environment?

Comment: Temporarily as a normal console app. Further it should be started as a Windows service. I am using configuration parameters from appsettings.json, not from command line.

Comment: You mention "ASP.NET Core 3.1" in your question, because of this I assumed that you are trying to run a Web App/API. Could you describe what you mean with Console App? Do you mean running it from the terminal with `dotnet run`?

Comment: Yes, it is a C# SOAP gateway to a Delphi-written system. It uses SoapCore package. No, it is a normal Windows executable file and I just double click it. It opens a Windows console for debugging purposes.

Comment: Ah ok. I get that you currently running the executable manually for testing purposes. I think that you will be better of using a webserver like IIS to host your .NET app in Production instead of configuring your own Windows Service. IIS makes it way easier to manage certificates and is available on most windows servers.

Comment: May be later. For now I would like that it just finally runs and is able to show some useful effect. I care more about doing things for which I am developing rather than doing it pretty / right. Lather I will change that.

Comment: Maybe the following section will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration. It explains how you can configure SSL certificates for Kestrel.

Comment: Thank you. HttpsDefaultCert seems to be my case. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure the certificates in `appsettings.json`. I think the `Certificates.Default` property would work for your case. You would need to set `AllowInvalid` to `true` to be able to use self-signed certificates.

Example setup `appsettings.json`:

```json
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000"
      },
      "HttpsDefaultCert": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:5004"
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "<path to .pfx file>",
        "Password": "$CREDENTIAL_PLACEHOLDER$",
        "AllowInvalid": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More examples and explanation can be found at the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration).

Comment: I have tested it - it leads to the same error as using UseUrls and UseSoapEndpoint. It doesn't matter whether I configure it directly in code or in Kestrel settings in appsettings.json. And I do not like to store certificate password as a plain text. My idea was that Windows certificate store already has a certificate for localhost. I thought, UseSoapEndpoint case would use it, but something is going wrong.

Comment: You can point it to the user certificate store: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#certificate-sources. Are you sure that you are accesing `https://localhost:5004`?

Comment: Changes to `appsettings.json` only apply when you use dotnet run or debug in Visual Studio. So this answer won't help on a production server with .NET SDK.

Comment: Lex Li: I tested in production environment, and settings from appsettings.json ARE accepted. May be you are confusing it with launchSettings.json

Comment: MaartenDev: What do you mean with "am I accessing?" It doesn't come to access. Application crashes immediately at start when using HTTPS. It runs on development machine where development certificate is installed.

Comment: I use "Certificates": {"Default": { "Subject": "localhost", "Store": "LocalMachine"}} and it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

If your intention is to manage certificates on your own (without following Microsoft's default resolution mechanism), explicitly ask Kestrel to use your certificate via a suitable function from `ListenOptions.UseHttps`,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-6.0#listenoptionsusehttps

> Most common one is `UseHttps(StoreName storeName, string subject, bool allowInvalid, StoreLocation location)`.

> Changes to `appsettings.json` only apply when you use `dotnet run` or debug in Visual Studio.